# Why is Input.GetKeyDown returning an error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to make an input for if the player presses the down arrow, but it returns an error when I do things such as `Input.GetKey` , `Input.GetKeyDown` and `Input.GetKeyUp` . Here is my code:

```
void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            if (touchingDown == true)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQdkc.png)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). first clue: when you get an error, it is _immensely_ helpful to _include_ said error in your question.

Comment: ... and include that error as *text* rather than as a screenshot. The error message is essentially text, so show it as text.

Comment: If you hover over `Input`, what type does it show? If you have a property called `Input`, that might be the problem. (You could fully qualify it as `UnityEngine.Input`.)

Comment: Image has been attached to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are importing an "Input" class from a wrong location.
Delete all imports that are somehow suspicious. You only need this one for Unity's input:

```
using UnityEngine;
```

Comment: The only things I have imported are Unity Engine, System Collections, and System Collections Generic.

Comment: Try a new file and add exactly the sample code from here to see whether that works: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html If it does, compare accurately with your file. Keep in mind that the filename needs to be the name of the class, so "ExampleClass".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to constantly do something while the key is held down, you use the **Input.GetKey** function. If you want to do something once on a key press, you use the **Input.GetKeyDown** function, as this will evaluate to true only once, until the key is released and pressed again. It is important that you understand the difference between the two. Finally, you should always check for input in the **Update** function

Comment: I know all this and in the code I showcased, it is in fact, inside of the update function. My problem is that writing 'GetKeyDown' returns an error.

Comment: How is a WinForms project relevant in Unity?